# Not receiving CountDownTimer callbacks in Service

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer

I have a Bound service which collects locations for 3 minutes every 15 minutes. I start a CountDownTimer once the Service is connected in `onServiceConnected` of `ServiceConnection`. 
I receive all the Timer callbacks (`onFinish`) (`onTick`) perfectly as far the Activity which `bindService` is visible.
When Device is locked I do not receive any updates from the timer.

MyLocationService

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements MyTimerListener{

    private IBinder mBinder = new MyLocationBinder(); 

    public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = new MyLocationManager(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class MyLocationBinder extends Binder
    {
        public MyLocationService getService()
        {
            return MyLocationService.this;
        }
    }

    public void startFetchingLocations()
    {
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.startFetchingLocations();
            if(publishPeriodCountDownTimer != null) {
                publishPeriodCountDownTimer.cancel();
                publishPeriodCountDownTimer = null;
            }
            publishPeriodCountDownTimer = new MyCountTimer(gpsPublishPeriod * 60 * 1000, 1000, MyLocationService.this);
            publishPeriodCountDownTimer.start();    
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeFinished() {
        //Start fetching locations
        locationManager.startFetchingLocations(); //Start 3 min CountdownTimer
    }


    @Override
    public void onTick() {

    }

    public void onAllLocationsRecieved(ArrayList<Location> locations)
    {
        //Do stuff on Locations

        locationManager.stopFetchingGPS(); //Stops 3 min countdownTimer
    }
}
```

MyActivty

```
public class MyActivity
    {

            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                btnStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                MyNoificationManager.cancelAllNotifications();

                if (!isLocationServiceBound) {
                    Intent locServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);    
                    bindService(locServiceIntent, locationServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                }
        }

        private ServiceConnection locationServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                isLocationServiceBound = false;

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                MyLocationBinder locationBinder = (MyLocationBinder) service;
                locationService = locationBinder.getService();
                isLocationServiceBound = true;
                locationService.startFetchingLocations();
            }
        };
    }
```

It works as expected when the Activity is visible. The timer doesn't provide any `onTick()` or `onTimeFinished()` callbacks when the device is locked.
What could be the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

The CountDownTimer will not work when the phone goes to sleep mode. This is by design and it's to save battery life.

Alternately you can use android.app.AlarmManager instead to achieve your goal. Following is the sample code how to do that. Set the alaram like below

```
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);
   intent.putExtra("need_to_fetch_loc", true);
   PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, gpsPublishPeriod * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

Add the following method to your MyLocationService class

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     if(locationManager!= null && intent.getBooleanExtra("need_to_fetch_loc", false))
     {
         locationManager.startFetchingLocations();
     }

     return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
 }
```